# Probability and Intersections

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between conditional probability and dependent events. Even then, I'm not sure if that's what I'm having issues with.

**NB** This is not a homework problem. I am doing a stats course, but I've made all these variables up to help me understand.

Let's say, I have 3 "bags":

$\mathbf{A}$ = {*5*, *6*, *7*, *8*}

$\mathbf{B}$ = {*n*, *o*, *p*, *q*, *r*}

$\mathbf{C}$ = {*red*, *blue*, *green*}

So, going through some basics, I think I have these right.

If:

- $\mathbf{A}_{5}$ = "the probability of getting a *5* from bag $\mathbf{A}$"
- $\mathbf{A}_{6}$ = "the probability of getting a *6* from bag $\mathbf{A}$"
- $\mathbf{A}_{<7}$ = "the probability of getting an element less than ** from bag $\mathbf{A}$"
- $\mathbf{A}_{5 or 6}$ = "the probability of getting a *5*, or a *6* from bag $\mathbf{A}$"
- $\mathbf{B}_{consonant}$ = "the probability of getting a consonant from bag $\mathbf{B}$"
- $\mathbf{B}_{vowel}$ = "the probability of getting a vowel from bag $\mathbf{B}$"
- $\mathbf{C}_{primary}$ = "the probability of getting a primary colour (*red* or *blue*) from bag $\mathbf{C}$"

**Independent events**

Then P($\mathbf{A}_{5 or 6}$) = P($\mathbf{A}_{5}$ $\cup$ $\mathbf{A}_{6}$) = P($\mathbf{A}_{5}$) + P($\mathbf{A}_{6}$) = $\frac{1}{4}$+$\frac{1}{4}$ = $\frac{2}{4}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$.

Then P($\mathbf{A}_{5}$ $\cup$ $\mathbf{B}_{vowel}$) (*ie*, drawing once from bag $\mathbf{A}$ and once from bag $\mathbf{B}$ and getting a *5* or a *vowel*) = $\frac{1}{4}$+$\frac{1}{5}$ =  $\frac{5}{20}$+$\frac{4}{20}$ = $\frac{9}{20}$.

**Dependent events**

Drawing twice from bag $\mathbf{A}$ and getting a *5* and then a *6* = P($\mathbf{A}_{5 and 6}$) = P($\mathbf{A}_{5}$ $\cap$ $\mathbf{A}_{6}$) = $\frac{1}{4}$ . $\frac{1}{4}$  = $\frac{1}{16}$

**Conditional events**

Drawing twice from bag $\mathbf{A}$ and the probability of getting a *6* given I've already drawn a *5* = P($\mathbf{A}_{6}$|$\mathbf{A}_{5}$) = $\dfrac{P(\mathbf{A}_{5} \cap \mathbf{A}_{6})}{P(\mathbf{A}_{5})}$ = $\dfrac{\frac{1}{16}}{\frac{1}{4}}$ = $\frac{4}{16}$ = $\frac{1}{4}$

**Problem**
My problem comes in that I don't understand the semantic diference between the last two examples. How is it different to ask the probability of a 5 and then 6 as opposed to a 6 assuming I already have a 5?

I also fall apart when I have to stitch them together, eg. What is the probability that I would get a *primary colour* given a *consonant* given a *5*? Is that soemthing like...

P($\mathbf{C}_{primary}$|$\mathbf{B}_{consonant}$|$\mathbf{A}_{5}$)

= P($\mathbf{C}_{primary}$|$\dfrac{\mathbf{B}_{consonant} \cap \mathbf{A}_{5}}{\mathbf{A}_{5}}$)

= P($\dfrac{\mathbf{C}_{primary} \cap \dfrac{\mathbf{B}_{consonant} \cap \mathbf{A}_{5}}{\mathbf{A}_{5}}}{\dfrac{\mathbf{B}_{consonant} \cap \mathbf{A}_{5}}{\mathbf{A}_{5}}}$)

and I'm not even sure where to start with the numerator on that.

So in summary:

- How is it semantically different to ask the probability of "a *5* and then a *6*" as opposed to "a *6* assuming I already have a *5*"?
- How does one do a $\cap$ on a fractional as in the last equation?
- Do I have this all correct?

Comment: Concerning the independent events: In general $P\left(A\cup B\right)=P\left(A\right)+P\left(B\right)-P\left(A\cap B\right)$
and $A$ and $B$ are independent iff $P\left(A\cap B\right)=P\left(A\right)P\left(B\right)$.
This leads to $P\left(\mathbf{A}_{5}\cup\mathbf{B}_{vowel}\right)=P\left(\mathbf{A}_{5}\right)+P\left(\mathbf{B}_{vowel}\right)-P\left(\mathbf{A}_{5}\right)P\left(\mathbf{B}_{vowel}\right)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{5}=\frac{8}{20}=\frac{2}{5}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some inaccuracies in your understanding. The event you describe as $\mathbf{A}_{5}\cup\mathbf{B}_{vowel}$ belongs to the sample space $\Omega:\mathbf{A}\cup\mathbf{B}=\{5,6,7,8,n,o,p,q,r\}$ and is NOT the event "drawing once from bag A and once from bag B and getting a 5 or a vowel".

$\mathbf{A}_{5}\cup\mathbf{B}_{vowel}$ describes the event of picking once from $\Omega$ and the result being a 5 or a vowel:

$P(\mathbf{A}_{5}\cup\mathbf{B}_{vowel})=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{9}=\frac{2}{9}$ ->(hint: $(P(\mathbf{A}_{5}\cup\mathbf{B}_{vowel})=P(\mathbf{A}_{5}|\Omega\cup\mathbf{B}_{vowel}|\Omega)$

For sequences of (independent) experiments you have to consider the new sample space $\Omega':\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{A}=\{(5,5),(5,6),(5,7),...\}$ containing 16 elements of all combinations. In that light the probability of the event $E_{56}$ "Drawing twice from bag A and getting a 5 and then a 6" is:

$P(\mathbf{E}_{56})=1/16$

The event "Drawing twice from bag A and the probability of getting a 6 given I've already drawn a 5" can be written as ($x$ stands for 'any' pick):

$P(\mathbf{E}_{x6}|\mathbf{E}_{5x})=\frac{P(\mathbf{E}_{x6}\cap\mathbf{E}_{5x})}{P(\mathbf{E}_{5x})}=\frac{P(\mathbf{E}_{56})}{P(\mathbf{E}_{5x})}=1/4$

The difference between the joint and the conditional probability is that the first points to the ratio of the number of desired events to the total events in $\Omega'$. It is implied that $P(\mathbf{E}_{56})=P(\mathbf{E}_{56}|\Omega')$. The conditional probability points to the ratio of the number of desired events to the number of events in the set that you condition upon $E_{5x}:\{(5,5),(5,6),(5,7),(5,8)\}$. Hope this helps for your last problem as well.

Comment: Awesome thank you for pointing out my mistakes. It's super helpful. :-) I understand your last paragraph, but I'm having difficulty discerning between when to use the conditional vs joint. I think I now have a much better understanding of the differences between the two, but I'm still struggling to equate each of conditional and join to real world examples.

Comment: Looking at the way the OP describes it I am more willing to believe that $\mathbf{A}_{5}\cup\mathbf{B}_{vowel}$ should be seen as an event in $\Omega=\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B}$

Comment: @Drew Don't mix up events and probabilities. $\mathbf{A}_5$ for instance should not be described as 'the probability that...' but as 'the event that..' This event has a probability $P(\mathbf{A}_5)$. Secondly you can only speak of events if it is clear allready what is going to happen. 'Are you going to draw from bag A? Twice maybe? Do you put the 5 back if it is drawn?' That sort of things. Only in a steady context you can speak of events.

Comment: Description must be more look like: '$\mathbf{A}_5$ is the event of drawing a 5 if at random an element is drawn from bag A'.

Comment: @drhab you are right, it seems that $\mathbf{A}_{5}\cup\mathbf{B}_{vowel}$ is what you describe